# Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

We have C# components deployed on newly established server. We have checked the machine.config and web.config files with that of existing server. Also, DB provider factory for MySQL is included in machine.config file. Still we are getting the exception while running C# components.
Exception is :
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net
 Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Do we need to restart the server after changes made in machine.config?

Any help regarding this, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple machine.config files in your \Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\vXXXX\Config directories. Take a look at both of the v2 and v4 machine.config files. There should be four files in total to look at. Check for the following :

It could be that there are extra tags that are making this happening. Check for any EXTRA, self terminated  tag in those files. Open and compare all of them.  It looks like this and is very easy to miss:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
       <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" ... />
       <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" ... />
       <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
       <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
    </DbProviderFactories>
    <DbProviderFactories/>
<system.data>
```

Notice the SELF CLOSING  tag.  Clean this up by keeping the one after the last item and deleting the self closing one at the end. In this sample :

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" ... />
      <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" ... />
      <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
      <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data ... />
   </DbProviderFactories>
<system.data>
```

Make sure then to reboot, walk away and come back and it should work...

Hope this helps.